# Starting Adobe Acrobat without toolbar and side panes

Tags: windows, command-line, adobe-acrobat, parameters

I found that it's possible to start Acrobat without toolbar with the following command:

```
Acrobat.exe" /A "toolbar=0" "%1"
```

and that it's possible to hide the navpanes with the following:

```
Acrobat.exe" /A "navpanes=0" "%1"
```

However I found no reference about how to combine these parameters.

Do you know how to make both of them work simultaneously?

Comment: Hmm... which version of Acrobat? And what, exactly, is `"toolbar=0"` supposed to do (screenshot?)? Because it appears to have no effect at all on my Acrobat X Pro. `navpanes=0` gets rid of the bookmarks, etc, panes on the left.

Comment: OK, thanks for the tip, I found it. On Acrobat 10 it's not possible. The reference documents stating the /A switches were for older version. It's a pity, typical Adobe style...
http://forums.adobe.com/message/3340147

Comment: You may want to look into the "[Read Mode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/standard/using/WSe6c6ee3e336ebb13-630c189912be99aedab-7fff.html#WS058ac72617541aaf-453c26512b229efb52-7fff)" of Acrobat X. It removes the toolbars and navigation panes. Unfortunately, I can't find a command line switch to open in Read Mode.

Comment: It seems that both of them are disabled by command line or by user preferences. Typical Adobe... So far the best tweak I found is to set it to navpanes=0 and press F8 when starting, this way it's just one button.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
/A "toolbar=0&navpanes=0"
```

Comment: Adobe Acrobat SDK version 8.1 docs say you can also use "#". Spaces are not allowed.